# What is wrong with this rewrite rule in a .htaccess file?

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond search.php
RewriteCond {$QUERYSTRING} category=restauran(.*)city=Montrea(.*)$ 
RewriteRule search.php.* http://www.mynewsite.fak/$1 [P]
```

The idea is to redirect any calls to search.php with `category=restaurant` and `city=Montreal` in the querystring to http://www.mynewsite.fak with path intact so for example:

```
myoldsite.fak/folderA/folderB/search.php?blah=blah...
```

goes to

```
mynewsite.fak/folderA/folderB/search.php?blah=blah...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this seems to be working for me:

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} category=restaurant(.*)&city=Montreal

RewriteRule ^search.php$ http://www.fakesite/data/testing/search.php [P,QSA]

Thanks newfurniturey.

Answer (score 1):

Three things that I notice.

The first is, you mispelled the query-string variable in your example. It should be `{$QUERY_STRING}`. This may be enough to fix the issue, but there are a few other suggestions as well.

The second is that your `RewriteCond` for the query-string is doing a greedy-match for each value. Try updating to match content that can specifically go in the fields, like `\w+` for instance.

The third is the `RewriteRule` itself. You can drop the `.*` from the current page name, and change the rule to something more suitable, such as `[R=301, L]`. This will cause the rule to "redirect" with an HTTP 301 (permanent redirect) header, and the `L` states it's the last rule to apply.

Altogether, this should (potentially) work:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond {$QUERY_STRING} category=(\w+)&city=(\w+)$
RewriteRule ^search.php$ http://www.mynewsite.fak/$1 [R=301, L]
```

Comment: Thanks for responding,  
I want use [P] as this is a call used by some ajax apps and so it needs to be transparent to the client side as I can't change all those apps.  Also my match is greedy because the category and city parameters are not necessarily right together in the QS and not necessarily at the end.  trying it now like so and the rewrite doesn't happen 

RewriteCond {$QUERY_STRING} category=restaurant&city=Montreal       
RewriteRule ^search.php$ http://www.mysite.fak/data/testing/$1 [P]

of course the search.php file in in the /data/testing directory on both servers.